Какое расширение в VS Code добавляет комментарии с классами для каждого div?
Как называется расширение в vs code, который делает комментарии на каждый div и показывает в комментарии что это за класс?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Расширение называется HTML End Tag Labels

